Mock IPreferences from MAUI that returns DateTime
I'm not very good with Mock. I'm writing a test for a method that resets the value when the next day is +3 hours add. Iam using IPreferences interface from MAUI.
public void ResetMileageIfNewDay()
    {
        var lastUpdate = preferences.Get(_lastUpdateKey, DateTime.MinValue);
        var resetTime = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(3);
        
        if (lastUpdate.Date < resetTime)
        {
            preferences.Set(_mileageKey, 0.0);
            preferences.Set(_lastUpdateKey, DateTime.Now.Date);
            preferences.Set(_lastSentMileageKey, 0.0);
            _logger.LogInformation("Mileage reset due to new day at 3AM");
        }
    }

here's a test
[Test]
    public void ResetMileageIfNewDay_ShouldReset_WhenLastUpdateBeforeResetTime()
    {
        var preferencesMock = new Mock<IPreferences>();
        var lastUpdate = new DateTime(2024, 9, 18, 23, 0, 0);

        preferencesMock
            .Setup(p => p.Get(It.IsAny<string>(), DateTime.MinValue)) //Error here
            .Returns(lastUpdate);

        var service = new MileageService(preferencesMock.Object, default, default, default,default);

        service.ResetMileageIfNewDay();
        
        preferencesMock.Verify(p => p.Set("LastMileageUpdate", It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>()
            .ToString("o")), Times.Once);
    }

Eror in Setup DateTime.Minvalue
An expression tree cannot contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments

I tried doing ToString, so gets added, but it's not quite correct for my method
What's the problem? How can I make the lastUpdate value passed to the method?
I'm trying to pass mock values to a method

A Mock must mock all parameters even the optional ones you can ignore in standard code. IPreferences.Get has a third parameter sharedName that you must mock also.

The verify call has presumably the same problem. The third parameter is sharedname a string. SO simply use It.IsAny<string>() instead of DateTime.

Yeah, thanks a lot, I was just thinking the same thing.
preferencesMock.Setup(p => p.Get(“LastMileageUpdate”, DateTime.MinValue, null)).Returns(lastUpdate);

In Setup method you must define conditions for all parameters for a method call to be captured.
And as you can see in the docs:
public T Get<T> (string key, T defaultValue, string? sharedName = default);

has third parameter. Hence, the correct setup would look like:
preferencesMock
    .Setup(p => p.Get(It.IsAny<string>(), DateTime.MinValue, It.IsAny<string?>())) 
    .Returns(lastUpdate);

Similairly, Set method has the third default param, so you need to take it into account during verifying:
preferencesMock.Verify(
    p => p.Set(
        "LastMileageUpdate", 
        It.IsAny<DateTime>().ToString("o"),
        It.IsAny<string>()), 
    Times.Once);

You have also verified method with three parameters, but you used It.IsAny<DateTime>().ToString("o") as third parameter, which, I guess, was not on purpose.

This solves the first problem with the Get mock, but there is a second problem with the Verify on the Set mock

@KlausGütter I referred to the exact problem that was raised, but updated the answer :)
